# T-SQL- Sum over Partition by in combination with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a sum over partition by into a normal sql statement but the code won't work. Technology: SQL Server 2014

Here's the Code:

```
select  
     ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,ZSTR$,right(left(GABS$,3),2) as Region

    ,SUM(Nettobetrag) AS NettoUmsatz
    ,SUM(BRUTTOBETRAG) AS BruttoUmsatz
    ,SUM(Nettobetrag) over (partition by ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,right(left(GABS$,3),2))

from
     ArchivZBEW.PROD.sFCTS_G195
where 
    NETTOBETRAG<>0 and right(left(GABS$,3),2)<>'65' 
    and UTYP$ in('K','M','P')
group by
    ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,ZSTR$,right(left(GABS$,3),2)
```

As you can see, I try to get an output with all the columns in the first line and then different sums. NettoUmsatz and Bruttoumsatz are working fine, like expected - but now I Need another sum which ignores the "ZSTR$" field. I take this query as part of an CTE , so it would be nice to have it in this statement, otherwise i have to join the table twice and statement gets very slow.

ErrorCode: (in german):

> Die ArchivZBEW.PROD.sFCTS_G195.NETTOBETRAG-Spalte ist in der Auswahlliste ungültig, da sie nicht in einer Aggregatfunktion und nicht in der GROUP BY-Klausel enthalten ist.

Thanks to google translate:

> The archiveZBEW.PROD.sFCTS_G195.NETTOBETRAG column is invalid in the selection list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and is not contained in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I don't see the point of the `GROUP BY`  Please show sample data and expected output to make your question clearer.

Comment: Deutsche Fehlermeldungen bedeuten nichts für englische Leser. The archiveZBEW.PROD.sFCTS_G195.NETTOBETRAG column is invalid in the selection list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and is not contained in the GROUP BY clause. BTW, I don't even speak German.

Answer (score 5):

There's no specific problem in using SUM()OVER() with GROUP BY, but you were probably getting confused by the presence of SUM() in relation to the OVER, and forgetting that it's just another column that either needs to be SUMmed itself, or mentioned in the group by

This won't work:

```
SELECT
  a,
  SUM(b),
  SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY a) --this wont work: c is not mentioned in GROUP BY and this column is not an aggregate in the GROUP  BY sense
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 
  a
```

You either have to:

```
SELECT
  a,
  SUM(b),
  SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY a)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 
  a, c --make c something you group by
```

Or:

```
SELECT
  a,
  SUM(b),
  SUM(SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY a)) --inner sum is overed, outer is groupbyed
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 
  a
```

Or:

```
SELECT
  a,
  SUM(b),
  SUM(SUM(c)) OVER(PARTITION BY a) --inner SUM is groupbyed, outer sum is overed
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 
  a
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats it - thanks guys - was a big thought fault of mine - here's the Result:

```
select  DISTINCT
         ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,ZSTR$,right(left(GABS$,3),2) as Region

        ,SUM(Nettobetrag) over (partition by ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,ZSTR$,right(left(GABS$,3),2)) AS NettoUmsatz
        ,SUM(BRUTTOBETRAG) over (partition by ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,ZSTR$,right(left(GABS$,3),2)) AS BruttoUmsatz
        ,SUM(Nettobetrag) over (partition by ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,right(left(GABS$,3),2))

    from
         ArchivZBEW.PROD.sFCTS_G195
    where 
        --NETTOBETRAG<>0 
         right(left(GABS$,3),2)<>'65' 
         and UTYP$ in('K','M','P')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do below changes to get your code work:

```
select  
     ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,ZSTR$,right(left(GABS$,3),2) as Region

    ,SUM(Nettobetrag) AS NettoUmsatz
    ,SUM(BRUTTOBETRAG) AS BruttoUmsatz
   -- ,SUM(Nettobetrag) over (partition by ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,right(left(GABS$,3),2)) --commented as this is same as nettoUmsatz

from
     ArchivZBEW.PROD.sFCTS_G195
where 
    --NETTOBETRAG<>0 and  --sum has to be in having
    right(left(GABS$,3),2)<>'65' 
    and UTYP$ in('K','M','P')
group by
    ZABF$,ZUNR$,ZONR$,FPLN$,ZSTR$,right(left(GABS$,3),2)
having SUM(Nettobetrag) <> 0 --you might require this
```